# Polymer understanding attributes

Tags: polymer

I am relatively new to programming and have been reading up and watching videos on Polymer 1.0. But I am struggling to wrap my head around some of it, I have a general understanding of the elements and have been browsing the catalog. But I am not making certain connections. Such as how an item on a paper-menu element can be accessed by using on-iron-select calling _itemSelected?

how does on-iron-select link to paper-menu, and where is the documentation for this? I have looked trough the catalog and the bower repo I have downloaded and I can't see it.

I event build some basic elements and console logged this.$, even there I do not see this properties and attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to dive into what's going on, you need to understand Polymer 1.0's [Behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html).

Once that background info is established, the [source](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu/blob/901b0f580358c2f42d3f99cf2759c35fb310a045/paper-menu.html#L98) for the `<paper-menu>` element will point you in the right direction:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'paper-menu',
  behaviors: [
    Polymer.IronMenuBehavior
  ]
});
```

That [`Polymer.IronMenuBehavior`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-menu-behavior/blob/master/iron-menu-behavior.html) in turn makes use of its own set of behaviors, including [`Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/blob/master/iron-selectable.html). All those incremental behaviors create the overall functionality that you're seeing in the `<paper-menu>` element.

The nice thing about this approach is that any other element that also makes use of, e.g., `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior` will share the same general properties and methods, and a collection of elements feels like more of a coherent library.

Comment: Hey Jeff,thanks so much for the response, that makes sense and I have been running through all the linked items of the elements. I read the behavior guide on the polymer site and watched the polycast on them. Slowly getting it. But I am still unsure how on-iron-select works. This is probably a dumb question. How is this referenced or created?

Comment: The event is created using Polymer's `fire()` helper, at https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-selector/blob/master/iron-selectable.html#L283

Comment: Jeff you are a legend, thanks so much for helping out a noob. Greatly appreciated. Keep well